# SQL Server: SUM() with internal SELECT and sub SELECT. Error every time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

**QUESTION REWORDED**

I **had** the following column definition in an SQL statement with its own `GROUP BY`...

```
    SUM((SELECT a.CONT_TOT
     FROM  (SELECT   gl2.VisitID, gl2.MessageID, gl2.BillOfLading, COUNT(gl2.ContainerID) AS CONT_TOT
            FROM     dbo.tblEDIGoodsLines AS gl2
            WHERE    gl2.VisitID = gl.VisitID AND gl2.MessageID = gl.MessageID AND gl2.BillOfLading = gl.BillOfLading
            GROUP BY gl2.VisitID, gl2.MessageID, gl2.BillOfLading) AS a)) as TotalContainers,    

...etc
```

And I continuously got this error.

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

I am trying to get the TOTAL number of lines in the outside/bigger SELECT, and a total number of UNIQUE container counts in the TOTUCONT.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the greater SQL query, to illustrate my point about GROUP BY and sub-queries in an aggregate function like SUM():

```
SELECT
    gl.MessageID,
    gl.BillOfLading,
    gl.[Description],
    CASE WHEN e.PortID = 9 THEN 'Export'
      WHEN e.PortID = 11 THEN 'Import'
      ELSE 'ERROR'
    END AS Direction,
    CASE WHEN ctypes.ID IS NOT NULL
         THEN ctypes.ContainerSizeType 
         ELSE 'OTH'
    END AS CSizeType,
    ctypes.Length_ft + 'ft ' + ctypes.Height_ft + 'ft - ' + ctypes.Characteristics + ' (' + COALESCE(ctypes.Codes1995, ctypes.Codes1984) + ')' AS ContainerType,
    COUNT(gl.ContainerID) AS TOTCONT,
    SUM(a.CTOTAL) AS TOTUCONT
FROM tblEDIGoodsLines AS gl 
    INNER JOIN tblEDIEquipmentLines AS el 
        ON el.MessageID = gl.MessageID AND
           el.ContainerID = gl.ContainerID
    INNER JOIN tblEDI AS e
        ON CHARINDEX(e.MessageID, gl.MessageID) > 0 AND
           e.VisitID = gl.VisitID AND
           CHARINDEX('EXCEL', e.MessageRelease) = 0 AND
           e.Status = 1
    LEFT JOIN tblContainerTypesISO6346 AS ctypes 
        ON ctypes.Codes1984 = el.SizeAndType OR 
           ctypes.Codes1995 = el.SizeAndType
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT gl2.MessageID, gl2.VisitID, gl2.BillOfLading, gl2.description, COUNT(DISTINCT gl2.ContainerID) AS CTOTAL
              FROM tblEDIGoodsLines AS gl2 
              WHERE gl2.MessageID = gl.MessageID 
                AND gl2.VisitID = gl.VisitID 
                and gl2.BillOfLading = gl.billoflading 
                and gl2.description = gl.description
              GROUP BY gl2.MessageID, gl2.VisitID, gl2.BillOfLading, gl2.description) AS a
        ON a.MessageID = gl.MessageID AND a.VisitID = gl.VisitID AND a.BillOfLading = gl.billoflading AND a.description = gl.description
WHERE gl.Status = 1
  AND gl.VisitID = 22987
GROUP BY
    gl.MessageID,
    gl.BillOfLading,
    gl.[Description],
    CASE WHEN e.PortID = 9 THEN 'Export'
         WHEN e.PortID = 11 THEN 'Import'
         ELSE 'ERROR'
    END,
    CASE WHEN ctypes.ID IS NOT NULL
         THEN ctypes.ContainerSizeType 
         ELSE 'OTH'
    END,
    ctypes.Length_ft + 'ft ' + ctypes.Height_ft + 'ft - ' + ctypes.Characteristics + ' (' + COALESCE(ctypes.Codes1995, ctypes.Codes1984) + ')'
```

The above does not work anyway, as I am trying to solve this by separating the "column" SELECT into it's own JOIN query, but now I get this:

> The multi-part identifier "gl.MessageID" could not be bound.

So this implies, that the LEFT JOIN (SELECT...) is invalid?

Thanks again

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a data sample to explain further:

[image]

So you can see the outcome I want, TOTCONT to add up to '4'. That's easy - just count the number of rows, but TOTUCONT to count only the Container ID once.

Comment: Adding sample input and output data might make it easier for others to understand your question.

Comment: Your SQL looks valid, are you sure that's the line giving the error?

Comment: @Nick yes. That's what I thought too, according to the syntax

Comment: You can use multiple CTEs to solve this problem, which can refer to results from earlier CTEs to tackle the aggregation problem. Using this method avoids having to replicate the `CASE` statements and the `ContainerType` calculation in a `GROUP BY`. The database has to follow a similar execution plan (unlikely to affect performance). This would make each part of the your code more modular and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try refactoring the code to be more like this (as I commented earlier). It may also help with the other issues you are dealing with:

```
with cte_ctotal
as (
    select gl2.MessageID,
        gl2.VisitID,
        gl2.BillOfLading,
        gl2.description,
        COUNT(distinct gl2.ContainerID) as CTOTAL
    from tblEDIGoodsLines as gl2
    group by gl2.MessageID,
        gl2.VisitID,
        gl2.BillOfLading,
        gl2.description
    ),
cte_containers
as (
    select
    a.ContainerID,
    gl.MessageID,
    gl.VisitID,
    gl.BillOfLading,
    gl.Description,
    case 
        when e.PortID = 9
            then 'Export'
        when e.PortID = 11
            then 'Import'
        else 'ERROR'
        end as Direction,
    case 
        when ctypes.ID is not null
            then ctypes.ContainerSizeType
        else 'OTH'
        end as CSizeType,
    ctypes.Length_ft + 'ft ' + ctypes.Height_ft + 'ft - ' + ctypes.Characteristics + ' (' + COALESCE(ctypes.Codes1995, ctypes.Codes1984) + ')' as ContainerType,
    from tblEDIGoodsLines gl
    inner join tblEDIEquipmentLines el on el.MessageID = gl.MessageID
                                        and el.ContainerID = gl.ContainerID
    inner join tblEDI e on CHARINDEX(e.MessageID, gl.MessageID) > 0
                        and e.VisitID = gl.VisitID
                        and CHARINDEX('EXCEL', e.MessageRelease) = 0
                        and e.status = 1
    left join tblContainerTypesISO6346 ctypes on ctypes.Codes1984 = el.SizeAndType
                                              or ctypes.Codes1995 = el.SizeAndType
    where gl.status = 1
    and gl.VisitID = 22987
    )
select 
c.MessageID,
c.BillOfLading,
c.Description,
c.Direction,
c.CSizeType,
c.ContainerType,
COUNT(c.ContainerID) as TOTCONT,
SUM(COALESCE(ct.CTOTAL,0)) as TOTUCONT
from cte_containers c
left join cte_ctotal ct on ct.MessageID = c.MessageID
                       and ct.VisitID = c.VisitID
                       and ct.BillOfLading = c.billoflading
                       and ct.description = c.description
group by c.MessageID,
    c.BillOfLading,
    c.Description,
    c.Direction,
    c.CSizeType,
    c.ContainerType;
```

Comment: Yep that's what I did. In fact I went further and turned my CTE into a View, and linked it like a normal table. Easy peasy. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 (SELECT SUM(a.CONT_TOT)
 FROM  (SELECT   gl2.VisitID, gl2.MessageID, gl2.BillOfLading, COUNT(gl2.ContainerID) AS CONT_TOT
        FROM     dbo.tblEDIGoodsLines AS gl2
        WHERE    gl2.VisitID = gl.VisitID AND gl2.MessageID = gl.MessageID AND gl2.BillOfLading = gl.BillOfLading
        GROUP BY gl2.VisitID, gl2.MessageID, gl2.BillOfLading) AS a) as TotalContainers,
```

Comment: Again, this didn't work because the () around the entire SELECT, makes my bigger query send an error that there is no aggregate in the GROUP BY of the bigger query. I'll update my question to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify this to:

```
(SELECT COUNT(gl2.ContainerID)
 FROM dbo.tblEDIGoodsLines gl2
 WHERE gl2.VisitID = gl.VisitID AND
       gl2.MessageID = gl.MessageID AND
       gl2.BillOfLading = gl.BillOfLading
) as TotalContainers,
```

Notes:

- The outer `SUM()` is unnecessary.  You can do the aggregation in the subqueries.
- You do not need two levels of subqueries.
- The `GROUP BY` is unnecessary.  An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` always returns exactly one row, which is what you want for a scalar subquery.

Depending on the rest of your query, this still might not work in your full query.  If this is the case, then you should ask a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and (a simplified version of) the query that does not work.

Comment: As per my other replies. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
SUM(a.CONT_TOT) as TotalContainers
     FROM  (
       SELECT   COUNT(gl2.ContainerID) AS CONT_TOT
       FROM     dbo.tblEDIGoodsLines AS gl2
       WHERE    gl2.VisitID = gl.VisitID AND gl2.MessageID = gl.MessageID AND gl2.BillOfLading = gl.BillOfLading
       GROUP BY gl2.VisitID, gl2.MessageID, gl2.BillOfLading
     ) AS a,
```

You may need to use parentheses at the end depending on the use of the code.
I removed additional columns from the SELECT list as they are not needed to get the SUM() (unless you need them for something else?). 
Edit
Remove the WHERE clause from the last JOIN:

```
WHERE gl2.MessageID = gl.MessageID 
  AND gl2.VisitID = gl.VisitID 
  and gl2.BillOfLading = gl.billoflading 
  and gl2.description = gl.description
```

These conditions are applied in the ON clause.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work, as I tried it with outside parentheses. I get Column 'tblEDIGoodsLines.VisitID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. This is because the SUM() on it's own won't work with a FROM unless there is a SELECT before it, which throws the above error

Comment: I assumed that the code you posted is just part of the code you use and there is a SELECT before SUM() isn't there?

Comment: Thanks @forpas, but I get more counts in the unique case than the overall case. I know for a fact it should be less (based on Excel pivots)

Comment: I can't tell about the results you get. You are summing over the counters you get by the subquery. Maybe you can execute separately the subquery and check these counters.

Comment: Updated the question again, with data. Thanks

Comment: If you are asking *why you get these results* I must say I can't tell, because I don't have your data and even if I had it I don't think that I could understand the design of 4 tables. If you are asking how to get 4 from the column TOTCONT then you have to wrap the full query as a subquery, group by several columns and COUNT(*) will return 4. Also for TOTUCONT.

Comment: Bad data example. Sorry this question has gone outside the original problem. I have other problems with the overall SQL. Thanks for your time.